# How to find asset by it's number? Don't know what this number means

Tags: unity, assets

I need to find the asset that is displayed by this number inside my project. I guess this number means "GUID" but it's hard for me to understand what is it. Can you help me guys?[image: This picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Assets folder, look for files with a `.meta` extension. These are hidden by default, so you may need to show hidden files to see them.

These are how Unity manages references between files in your project, as well as storing import settings for assets. The part before the `.meta` extension is the name of the file or folder for which this file provides metadata information.

For example, here's a snippet of the meta file for a texture asset:

```
fileFormatVersion: 2 
guid: b16e813e7d26abe4bbbb349009f631be 
timeCreated: 1519570387 
licenseType: Free 
TextureImporter:   
    fileIDToRecycleName: {}
    externalObjects: {}
    serializedVersion: 4
    mipmaps:
        mipMapMode: 0
        enableMipMap: 1
        sRGBTexture: 1
        linearTexture: 0
        fadeOut: 0
        borderMipMap: 0
        mipMapsPreserveCoverage: 0
        alphaTestReferenceValue: 0.5
        mipMapFadeDistanceStart: 1
        mipMapFadeDistanceEnd: 3
```

The second line `guid:` shows the unique ID associated with this object. You can use something like Notepad++'s "Find in Files" to search your project folder for a meta file containing a particular GUID string.

Comment: Couldnt the built-in function [AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath.html) do the trick - or does it have different use?

Comment: Sounds like it would be worth posting that as an answer, @wondra :)

Comment: I am legitimately asking, never used it before and cannot verify it right now.

Comment: Hey guys, I tried it with Notepad++ and it worked. Thanks DMGregory for your advice, sir.